# Can i combine all generic view into one view in django

Tags: python, django

In my normal app. i have these six view for everymodel in my views.py file

```
Class SampleCreateView(CreateView)
     pass

Class SampleDetailView(DetailView)
     pass

Class SampleUpdateView(UpdateView)
     pass

Class SampleListView(listView)
     pass

Class SampleFormView(FormView)
     pass

Class SampleDeleteView(DeleteView)
     pass
```

Is there any easy way of doing that so that i have one view and performs all that functions.
by using some if else.

Or there is some other better solution .

One view per model will be good

Answer (score 1):

Generally different views are written so as to uncouple each other. You can write a function pass a parameter so that you can distinguish using the same and do the required stuff.
Besides Django also provides few builtin view.
You may want to look into tutorial for django.views.generic. 
You have the views such as CreateView,DetailView etc defined which you can use.